# Quando clicar no botão verificar se o valor da textbox contém em uma coluna da tabela

Tags: c#, sql-server

Como posso fazer uma verificação da textbox se contem este valor dentro da tabela na coluna da DataBase quando clicar no botão?

Fiz este código, mas não obtive exito:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString);

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM Alunos WHERE Numero ={txtNome.Text.Text}", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            int j = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            if (j == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("word" + txtNome.Text + "already exists!");
                ds.Clear();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Você testou o código?

Comment: O codigo esta meio incompleto, pode dar mais informações?

Sua duvida é na query? se sim, pode nos contar mais sobre suas estrutura?

Comment: Coloquei o código todo.

Comment: @ViniciusBittencourt O Código exibiu algum erro?

Comment: Não acontece nada quando clico no botão.

Comment: Coloquei um valor que não tinha na Coluna e apareceu a MessageBox. Como faço ao contrário?

Comment: Você não está abrindo a sua conexão (`conn.Open();`) e sua verificação está invertida. Você tem que verificar se existe alguma palavra, ou seja, se o `rowcount` é maior que 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Problema no código se encontra no seu *count*

```
int j = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
if (j == 0)
{
  MessageBox.Show("word" + txtNome.Text + "already exists!");
  ds.Clear();
}
```

Isto significa que a mensagem sera exibida somente se a quantidade de valores for 0, ou seja, se não existir.

Basta alterar

```
if (j == 0)
```

para

```
if (j > 0)
```

Assim, se algum valor existir(mais de uma linha), a mensagem sera exibida!